# How to get inner child in cloud function for Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

[image]

Here is my database and I want to trigger onWrite event on children of `PUBLISHED_CONTENT_LIKES`. When I add another userId under `publishedContentId1`, I can identify contentId as `publishedContentId1` in my cloud function using `event.params.pushId`.

```
exports.handleLikeEvent = functions.database.ref('/USER_MANAGEMENT/PUBLISHED_CONTENT_LIKES/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {

  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  //const userId = event.data.child(publishedContentId);
  //const test = event.params.val();
  const publishedContentId = event.params.pushId;

  var result = {"publishedContentId" : "saw"}
  // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
  // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
  // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
  return event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('PUBLISHED_CONTENTS/'+publishedContentId).set(result);
});
```

However I want to get newly added `userId` as well. How to get that userId using above event?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data that is being written under `event.data`. To determine the new user ID:

```
event.data.val().userID
```

I recommend watching the latest [Firecast on writing Database functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0) as it covers precisely this topic.