# Firebase Cloud Functions -how to get values from different child snapshots at the same ref

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have to get different values from different children at the same ref. In Swift I would do:

```
var sum = 0
var totalPosts = 0
var starRating = 0 // run some calculations on totalPosts + sum

let sneakersRef = Database.database().reference().child("sneakers").child(adidas_ABC) // postId
sneakersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() { return }

    if snapshot.hasChild("postCount") {
        let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "postCount")
            if let postCount = childSnapshot.value as? Int {
                
               self.totalPosts = postCount
            }
        }
    }

    if snapshot.hasChild("fans") {

        let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fans")

        for child in childSnapshot.children {

            let userId = child as! DataSnapshot

            for snap in userId.children {

                guard let dict = snap.value as? [String:Any] else { continue }

                let price = dict["price"] as? Int ?? 0

                self.sum += price
            }

            // update ref with value obtained from sum and create/update a starRating
        }
    }
})
```

**How would I do the same thing in Cloud Functions?** The code inside the `childSnapshot.forEach((child) => { }` below is what I need help with.

```
exports.updateValues = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const postId = data.postId; // adidas_ABC

    var sum = 0;
    var totalPosts = 0;
    var starRating = 0;

    const sneakersRef = admin.database().ref('sneakers').child(postId);

    sneakersRef.once('value', snapshot => {

        if (snapshot.exists()) {

            const postCount = snapshot.child("postCount").val();

            totalPosts = postCount

            const childSnapshot = snapshot.child("fans").val().userID;

            // the code in this loop is questionable
            childSnapshot.forEach((snap) => {

                const price = snap.child("price").val();

                sum += price
            })

            // run calculations to get starRating

            return sneakersRef.update({ "sum": sum, "starRating": starRating }).then(() => {            
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('something went wrong: ', error);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('doesn't exist');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my db layout:

```
@sneakers
   @adidas_ABC // same postId for anything dealing with adidas
      @fans // this might not exist in which case postCount would be zero
         @userId_XYZ
            @postId_123
               -condition: "used"
               -price: 100
               -type: shell_top
            @postId_456
               -condition: "new"
               -price: 500
               -type: yeezy
      -fanCount: 1
      -postCount: 2
      -sum: 600
      -starRating: 4
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you expect to get with `snapshot.child("fans").val().userID`. It does not seem you have a node named `userID`.

Comment: Ahhhh, maybe that's the issue. I followed this answer and I thought that it was some sort of wildcard for a userID https://stackoverflow.com/a/43498731/4833705

Comment: I thought that that would return anything under fans for example I thought that `snapshot.child("fans").val().userID` would get me `/fans/userId_XYZ`

Comment: I'll write an answer, as there is another key point that needs to be adapted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to adapt in your code:

1. You need to loop over the `user` objects and then you need to loop over each `post` of each `user` object. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) for more details.
2. You need to correctly manage the life cycle of your Cloud Function by returning the [Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining). As you will see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in the doc, it is **key** to terminate Cloud Functions that perform asynchronous processing by returning a JavaScript promise. In your case we return the Promise chain, which is a Promise, and which is composed of the Promises returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods (`once()` and `update()`) and by `then()`. For that we need to use the "promisified" version of the `once()` method (i.e. `once('value').then((snapshot) => {..})`) and not the callback version, which you used in your code.

So the following should do the trick:

```
exports.updateValues = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const postId = data.postId; // adidas_ABC

    var sum = 0;
    var totalPosts = 0;
    var starRating = 0;

    const sneakersRef = admin.database().ref('sneakers').child(postId);

    return sneakersRef   // Note the return here!! => We return the Promise chain
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const postCount = snapshot.child('postCount').val();

                totalPosts = postCount;

                const childSnapshot = snapshot.child('fans').val();

                Object.keys(childSnapshot).forEach((user) => {
                    const obj = childSnapshot[user];
                    Object.keys(obj).forEach((e) => {
                        const price = obj[e].price;
                        sum += price;
                    });
                });

                // I let you dealing with the calculations to get starRating

                return sneakersRef.update({ sum: sum, starRating: starRating });
            } else {
                console.log("doesn't exist");
                return null; // Note the return here
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('something went wrong: ', error);
            return null; // Note the return here
        });

});
```

Comment: I based my code off of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66202744/4833705 (I also wrote the question). The code works but is much simpler because for that question I did not need to get any childSnapshots/grandChildsnapshots. The `promise` is constructed different from yours but it does work as I haven't had any issues. My question to you is why does the `promise` from that answer work even though you said that the way i initially did it in my question above was incorrect?

Comment: I will answer later, not in front of my computer the moment!

Comment: ok thanks again, and extra thanks for pointing out `return null;`, I've looked at a ton of answers and I don't recall seeing anyone do that.

Comment: In your previous [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202383/firebase-cloud-functions-snapshot-foreach-then-is-not-a-function/66202744#66202744) you are also incorrectly managing the life cycle of your CF, because you don't return a Promise. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66425014/3371862) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197863/firebase-cloud-transactions-not-always-finishing/63197988#63197988)) where I explain that **sometimes**, the CF platform does not terminate the Function immediately and the asynchronous work can be completed...

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, thanks for letting me know that. I almost placed that code into a production app, luckily I'm still testing :)

Comment: We do `return null;` to, again, return a Promise in the CF. Actually the `catch()` function returns a Promise, like the `then()` one. You could very well do `return 1;` or `return 'abcd';`, or any other constant. You will find some examples of doing that in the **official** repository of CF samples, for example [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/5614dd71cddbe27512b41d662cc51d8d25f2a562/remote-config-diff/functions/index.js).

Comment: BTW, you may consider using a Transaction to update the prices sum. It depends on the exact function of your app, but if several users can concurrently modify a node, it would be better to use a Transaction.

Comment: cool, this is good stuff to know. It’s going take a while digest it all. I’m a Swift developer and Promises are very foreign to me. I have to learn though, one way or another.

Comment: You're right about a transaction. I forgot about that. I was so busy trying to figure out where I was going wrong with this. I'm going to adjust the code for it now!

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to go over Promises but I can't get a good grasp of it. I've been looking at the code that you posted and one thing that has me perplexed is this line `const price = obj[e].price;` The `obj` is the user, the `e` represents a `post`, and `price` is property, but what I can't understand is why did you have to add the `obj` in front of the brackets. Wouldn't this achieve the same exact thing: `const price = e.price;`? Notice I excluded the `obj[]`

Comment: "Wouldn't this achieve the same exact thing" => No, we are looping over the **keys** of the Object `obj`, so if we want to get the value, we need to do `obj[e]` (`e` holding the key value). On that we call the `price` property.

Comment: This is one of the places where I'm lost. If `e` is each individual post, we have the actual post itself. As the loop runs why can't we just pull the property on the `post` itself? Unless `e` isn't a post

Comment: Taking it a step back `const obj = childSnapshot[user];` must be the `post` then? I though it was the `user`. So `e` must be each key and we're looking for the price key? Basically `const price = obj[e].price;` is the same thing as saying `const price = post[key].price` Correct?

Comment: The **direct** properties (child nodes) of `fans` are the users (userId_XYZ, userId_ABC, userId_DEF, ...) For each if these users you may have several posts. So you need two loops (over users, and for each user, over posts). This is what I derived from the data model in your question. If I misunderstood the data model, you shoudl adapt this part of the asnwer! :-)

Comment: No no no, everything is fine on your part, it's my part that's having the issue. I'm trying to get a grasp on this. It's much different then firebase on the iOS/ Swift client. The problem here is I thought that `obj` was a user.

Comment: No worries :-) I do understand that you "are trying to get a grasp on this" and I'm happy to help you! I just explained what is the rationale of the proposed solution, based on my understanding. But my understanding could also very well be wrong!

Comment: I got it now. You loop over the users, then you loop over the keys of each post. See I thought it was you loop over the user, then you loop over each post, not each `key`. That's where I was lost => looping over each key .Thanks for the answer! :)